# Dictionary won't store the value after restart

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

Here is my code. This code is for managing fruit stocks in the shop. So you type in the name of the fruit, and the amount of it. If the fruit is not registered in the dictionary, it would add the fruit and it's value to the dictionary. If the fruit is registered, it would check if its value is bigger than the original value in the dictionary. If it's bigger, it will replace the amount, but if the typed amount is smaller than the original amount, it wouldn't do anything.

I used the code below for checking for the average of the fruits. So it counts how many fruits I have bought and it accumulates it. So that later on, I can use it to find out the average by dividing the number by how many times I have accumulated it.

```
items[fruit_t]["av"]+=(fruit_n)
```

Here is question. When ever i try to add things to dictionary, it prints for first time, but when I move on to add another fruit, previously added fruit disappears. I don't get what is wrong. Also, I want to use .append instead of += as shown above, but when ever I try to do that, there's an error. I want to use append because later on, I can use len() to count how many numbers are in   av
, sum up the av and divide by the len() value of av.

```
    import pickle
    def fruit():
        with open('fruits.pickle', 'a') as f:
            try:
                items = pickle.load(f)
            except ValueError:
                items = {"Apple":{"av":10,"count":10},"Banana":{"av":14,"count":14},"Orange":{"av":23,"count":23},"Watermelon":{"av":54,"count":54}}
            fruit_t = input("Please type in the name of the fruit: ")
            fruit_n = int(input("Please type in the amount of the fruit: "))
            if fruit_t in items:
                items[fruit_t]["av"]+=(fruit_n)
                if items[fruit_t]["count"] < fruit_n:
                    items[fruit_t]["count"] = fruit_n
            else: 
                items[fruit_t] = {"av":fruit_n,"count":fruit_n}
            with open('fruits.pickle', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(items, f)
            for k in items:
                print("{} monthly  {}".format(k,items[k]["av"]))
                print("{} total {}".format(k,items[k]["count"]))
            fruit()

    fruit()
```

Edited and working code.

```
    import pickle
def fruit():
    with open('fruits.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        try:
            items = pickle.load(f)
        except ValueError:
            items = {}
        fruit_t = input("Please type in the name of the fruit: ")
        fruit_n = int(input("Please type in the amount of the fruit: "))
        if fruit_t in items:
            items[fruit_t]["total"]+=(fruit_n)
            if items[fruit_t]["count"] < fruit_n:
                items[fruit_t]["count"] = fruit_n
        else: 
            items[fruit_t] = {"total":fruit_n,"count":fruit_n}
        with open('fruits.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(items, f)
        for k in items:
            print("{} monthly  {}".format(k,items[k]["total"]))
            print(items[k]["count"])
        fruit()

fruit()
```

Comment: 1) Check out the Counter-class in the collections-module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). 2) Your indentations seem to be way off. As it is now, you are calling ``fruit()`` recursively, without breaking conditions, and you are re-opening ``fruits.pickle`` within the context-manager.

Comment: @MrGumble would it be possible if you can help, improve this code?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question with a very different approach:

`pickle` will not load your pickled file because you are opening the file in 'appending'-mode in line 3.
You are not noticing the error as you have enclosed the loading in a `try`-statement. Instead, the exception is caught and your `items` are loaded from default.

Solution: Change mode in `open` in line 3 to `rb`.

Comment: oh, now I have changed it. Now I just have to find out how to get the average with av

Comment: To calculate the average, simply keep track of the running sum of ``count`` and the number of times you "buy" something. The average is then the sum divided by the number of buys. To store permanently, pickle can be used, but is an sub-optimal solution as the pickling protocol may change. Rely instead on text-based files for long-term storage of your results.

Comment: would it be possible to use csv? and please can you implement to your code with pickle/text file which works? Thank you

Comment: No. Your code is already pickling the result, and using text file depends entirely on your future usage of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are not correcting the code in the question, here is what is wrong:

1. You have specified 'appending' as the mode in `open` on line 3.
   This is not useful when you intend to *read* the file; instead use
   `r` for reading, perhaps `rb` for reading a binary file.
2. Dedent line 8 (`fruit_t = ...`) as this marks the exit from the context manager starting on line 3 (`with ...` is a context manager). This will close the file again, as you are done reading it. Dedent following lines.
3. You do not need to keep track of each "purchase"; you can instead rely on 1) the sum of purchases and 2) the count of purchases. Calculating the average is very easy then. You can therefore split your dictionary into two.
4. On line 12, your logic eludes me and it contradicts what you write in your question.

**Code example 1**

```
from collections import Counter

fruits = {'apple':0, 'banana':0}
purchases = Counter(fruits)
fruits = Counter(fruits)
## on purchase
fr = 'apple'
buy = 4
fruits[fr] += 4
purchases[fr] += 1
```

See what happens if you buy a fruit that is not yet present in the Counters (i.e. set `fr = 'mandarin'`).

Comment: so this is technically much better way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Comment: when i try this code, this doesn't add the previous value. So it doesn't store anything.

Comment: You will have to elaborate on what you mean by "this doesn't add the previous value". In which context?

Comment: Technically, a much better way depends on what your overall goal is. Why are you pickling your dictionary?

Comment: because I want the data stored in the pickle file, not the code. I was originally going to do this in csv, but someone told me to do this in pickle so I'm doing this in pickle.